# Call multiple getElementsByClassName() with JS

Tags: javascript, html, toggle

I am puzzling at the moment with getting my JS working on multiple class elements. Currently in the code it is only changing the display:none of the first div it can find. I have read some tutorials but until now I am unable to implement this into my js and getting it to work.

Is someone able to help me out with this?
Thanks in advance!

```js
function showHideEnglish() {
        var english = document.getElementsByClassName("text__english")[0]; 
  
        var german = document.getElementsByClassName("text__german")[0];
         german.style.display = "none";
        if(english.style.display == "block") {
                german.style.display = "none";             
          }
        else {
            english.style.display = "block";            
        }
    }

    function showHideGerman() {
        var english = document.getElementsByClassName("text__english")[0];
        var german = document.getElementsByClassName("text__german")[0];
        english.style.display = "none";
        if(german.style.display == "block") {
                 english.style.display = "none";
          }
        else {
             german.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="showHideEnglish();">English</button>
<button onclick="showHideGerman();">German</button>

<div class="text__english"style="display:block;">This text is English</div><br>
<div class="text__german" style="display:none;">dieser Text ist auf Deutsch</div><br>
<div class="text__english"style="display:block;">This text is English</div>
<div class="text__german" style="display:none;">dieser Text ist auf Deutsch</div>
```

Comment: The `[0]` means you're only fetching the first such elements. If you want to apply something to all elements of that class you have to loop through in some way.

Comment: Sorry for that. The HTML has various div's with class="text__english" and class="text__german" if I run the JS now it only switches one div to display:none but not both of them. What I am trying to achieve is that it would switch them both.

Comment: @RobinZigmond yeah, though up to now I've been unable to implement this loop and I can't see how to implement it in my current JS

Comment: As stated clearly [0] is handling the first div thats why only the first instances of them are changing. The verbose way is to copy the same lines and change them to [1] though not the ideal.

Comment: @tagliatelli How could I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works no matter how many elements are on the page:

```js
function showHideEnglish() {
        var german = document.getElementsByClassName("text__german");
        for (var i = 0; i < german.length; i++) {
            german[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        var english = document.getElementsByClassName("text__english"); 
        for (var i = 0; i < english.length; i++) {
            english[i].style.display = "block";            
        }
     }
    
     function showHideGerman() {
        var german = document.getElementsByClassName("text__german");
        for (var i = 0; i < german.length; i++) {
            german[i].style.display = "block";
        }
        var english = document.getElementsByClassName("text__english"); 
        for (var i = 0; i < english.length; i++) {
            english[i].style.display = "none";            
        }
     }
```

```html
    <button onclick="showHideEnglish();">English</button>
    <button onclick="showHideGerman();">German</button>

    <div class="text__english" style="display:block;">This text is English</div><br>
    <div class="text__german" style="display:none;">dieser Text ist auf Deutsch</div><br>
    <div class="text__english" style="display:block;">This text is English</div>
    <div class="text__german" style="display:none;">dieser Text ist auf Deutsch</div>
```

Comment: It does not hide the other element at the moment. It should act like it is switching between language

Comment: @Marcel see my edit: it now just toggles between the languages.